# Git push -u origin master not working after repository rename

Tags: git

I have created a BitBucket repository and then have made a small change in a file in my local repository.  I did a git commit and then a git push -u origin master.  But I get an error saying that its not found.  What must I do?

Comment: check your `git remote` and tell me what you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset your remote path:

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin <your_new_repos_remote_path>
```

Comment: my local path is still the old one too.

Comment: what do I replace <your_new_repos_remote_path> with?

Comment: But you're trying to push them to remote.

Comment: Sth like `git@bitbucket.org:kjuly/arepo.git`, with your new name.